# Logstash extract fields from message field located in Json

Tags: java, logstash, log4j2

I have some files including logs with json format. I can use log4j2-core libraries. Here you can find single line of log.

```
    {"instant":{"epochSecond":1628692763,"nanoOfSecond":792000000},"thread":"AWT-EventQueue-0","level":"INFO","loggerName":"com.client.logon.form.Logon","message":"errortype: SECURITY logContent:User Log on user 1","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger","threadId":23,"threadPriority":6,"@timestamp":"2021-08-11T17:39:01.025+0300"}
```

I need to show fields like thread, level, logger... in elastic server. In addition to this I need to also extract fields "errorType" and "logContent" by manipulating message field ""errortype: SECURITY logContent:User Log on user 1"

Here I use  following configuration but it does not work. Each log line does not need to have errorType field. It will be included if level is ERROR. For other levels, I can have logContent inside "message" field

```
filter{

json{
    source => "message"
}
grok {
    match => {
        "message" => [
            "errortype:%{GREEDYDATA:errorType}  %{GREEDYDATA:logContent}"
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I dont think you need a `grok` here. You already have a `json` object. Remove the fields that you don't want by using `mutate { remove => ` ... show us exactly which fields you want to see from the input that you have it up in your question

Comment: Thanks for reply. I can get fields level, loggerName, message... etc. But I want to also extract errortype, logContent from "message" field. message field stores String